# Prevent Users Creating Table

Tags: security, ms-access, permissions

I'm trying to secure an MS Access 2003 mdb using the workgroup security. I've got most of it set up (using a new MDW etc), but I can't stop people creating new tables in the database, if they've got access to open it. Am I missing something?

None of the accounts have any permissions allowed, I'm doing it all through groups.
Users only have Open\Run access to the database, no access to <New Tables/Queries> and only "Read Data" access on all the other tables, including the `MSys*` tables.

Any thoughts or am I trying to do the impossible?

--Update--

I've tried using the wizard as suggested, but that still leaves me with the same problem. I created a blank database & ran the wizard on it. Assigned 2 users, Me & User, and removed all access to the standard groups. I added Me into the Admin group & User to the Read Only group.

Not using the MDW denies access, as expected. Logging in as Me allows full access (Design things, add data, delete data, etc), logging in as User will allow read data inexisting tables, but not add data or design them (as expected), but it will still allow creation of a new table, which User will then have full access to add, delete etc.

Comment: You've not secured it correctly. You have to run the security wizard which creates a new workgroup file that has a different ADMIN group than the default workgroup files (which all have the same ADMIN group). The usual approach is to remove all permissions for the built-in groups and users and use customer groups to provide access.

Comment: I've added more detail to what I've tried so far, which included the Wizard. I'm beginning to think this is a limitation of workgroup security I'm going to have to work round in Code.
B.

Comment: BTW: I've used a quote of yours as a sig for a long time as it makes me smile every time:
Quote (David W. Fenton):
We could be confused in exactly the same way, but confusion might be like Nulls, and not comparable.

Comment: Wow, I have no recollection of such a quotation. I used to be smart!

Comment: Have you removed the permissions on the top-level database object? I've forgotten the details here but I know I have an app that is secured only insofar as it prevents the creation of tables (everything else is wide open). It's not accesible to me for checking how it's done, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, over a year after posting this question, I have another go at solving it, but his time with success!

I came across the [Microsoft Accesss Permissions Explorer](http://www.grahamwideman.com/gw/tech/access/permexpl/index.htm) and this showed that the standard ways of securing the database, both manually and using the wizard still give the **Users** group explicit *Create* permsissions on the Tabes Container. This same software also allows the revoking of said permissions, so now I can have a fully secured database, where any user can access the mdb without using a special MDB, but they are only able to access and edit the data I want them to.

Comment: Did that change also prevent the users saving new queries?  Sorry for asking this question so late, but I only just found this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can your users use the runtime version of msAccess? They will not have the ability to create any new Access object, such as table, query, form, etc.

And runtime version is free, so you'll also spare on licences!

Comment: The runtime version will still allow tables to be created using DAO (or ADO), so this won't work. :-(

Comment: I am not really sure about that. That would be true if users have the possibility to generate some VB code and use it to send DDL instructions on your access file, but this will not be possible with a runtime version of Access. Then, if your users are smart enough to do that kind of things, they could then write the same code in an Excel or Word module to create these tables. In this case youu'll have to switch to SQL SERVER to enhance some real security policy on your database.